# Immutable partition on Gparted Live

Tags: ubuntu, image-resizing, partition

I'm running Gparted Live on a external hard disk so that I can edit the size of a partition on my computer hard disk.
When I access Gparted, I find the following scenario:

[image]

In order to asign the free memory to my extended partition I resize it this way:

[image]

Know I should be able to resize my sda5 partition and asign it the full free memory, but I can't I don't know why. If I try to resize sda6 (linux-swap) I can:

[image]

But the problem comes when I try to resize my sd5 (ext4):

[image]

It seems to be in its max size and I can't assing it the free memory, but I can do it on my linux-swap... Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resize a partition it must have unallocated space immediately adjacent to it.  In the situation described above one would need to move the swap sda6 partition to the right first to free up unallocated space between the sda5 and sda6 partitions.